# Oracle: select just last update of date

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have the following query that return me: 100 rows

```
SELECT uni_id, uni_mast_id, uni_type
  FROM UNIVERSITIES 
 WHERE uni_master ='SO88'AND uni_stat= 'OK'
```

now i need to do a join with another table and to obtain last entry of that day then:

```
SELECT uni_id, uni_teach_name, MAX(cal_update), cal_status
  FROM UNIVERSITIES
  LEFT JOIN CALENDAR
    ON unı_id = cal_id
 WHERE uni_master = 'SO88'
   AND uni_stat = 'OK'
   AND cal_name = 'REGISTRED'
 GROUP BY uni_id, uni_teach_name, uni_stat
 ORDER BY cal_update
```

but this query gives me 102 records, because `cal_update` appears **2** times.
One for example with date : `22-OCT-2020 11:34:55` another for the same `uni_id` at time `22-OCT-2020 11:30:22`

I want just to get the max date for that date, not both.
In this case the query with the join needs to return the same records of the first select query.

Comment: What's the version of the database ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do what you want using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT UNI_ID, UNI_TEACH_NAME, CAL_UPDATE, CAL_STATUS
FROM (SELECT U.UNI_ID, U.UNI_TEACH_NAME, C.CAL_UPDATE, C.CAL_STATUS,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY U.UNI_ID, TRUNC(C.CAL_UPDATE) ORDER BY C.CAL_UPDATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM UNIVERSITIES U LEFT JOIN
           CALENDAR C
           ON U.UNI_ID = C.CAL_ID AND C.CAL_NAME = 'REGISTRED'
      WHERE U.UNI_MASTER = 'SO88' AND
            U.UNI_STAT= 'OK'                
     ) UC
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

I have to guess where the columns come from, because the question is not clear.  Any filtering columns from `CALENDAR` should be in the `ON` clause if you are using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: it gives me missing right parenthesis regarding this place FROM UNIVERSITIES U
           CALENDAR C

Comment: if I run the query inside the parenthesis it gives me the message: SQL command not properly ended of course without aliasing

Comment: @StoreCode - it's missing the `JOIN` keyword between `UNIVERSITIES U` and `CALENDAR C`. I've added `LEFT JOIN` to the answer; but having `C.CAL_NAME` in the where clause will turn it back to an inner join; so if you do want an outer join, move that clause before the `WHERE`.

Comment: This query gives me less rows as expected, around 91, with duplicated id

Comment: @StoreCode - are you getting fewer rows because of the inner/outer join issue I mentioned? Have you moved `AND C.CAL_NAME = 'REGISTRED' from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause? You'll still get duplicate IDs if a calendar was updated on different days - but that's what you asked for.

Comment: I want only the last entry in order of time (update) for that UNI_ID university. If in a day we have 2 updates i want last one, only that.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: your query it's ok but i collect duplicated site id, because the date of cal_update appears not trucated

Comment: @StoreCode . . . `cal_update` is not truncated, but there should only be one per day.  If you just want the latest, remove the `trunc()` from the `partition by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but as result  i get two rows for the same day, I want only last update. In fact i collected 150 rows

Comment: @StoreCode . . . The calculation of seqnum guarantees that there is only one row per `uni_id` per day.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry to insist, but by an university i collect all the updates till 2017. I m using your query without changing anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the last part of the query, while aliasing the `MAX(cal_update)` with `cal_update` , as

```
ORDER BY cal_update DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

for DB version `12c+` to descendingly order by the concerned column in order to pick the record with the latest value for that column.

`WITH TIES` option stand for bringing all records with the same datetime values, might be replaced with `ONLY` in order to bring only one row even for those cases occur.

*The column `call_status`(within the select list) should be removed which's a non- aggregated column*

Comment: we use oracle 11, your suggestion doesn't work, sorry for that
oracle ide: 19.1

Comment: Won't this return a single row; rather than a single row per university?

Comment: yes, you're right @AlexPoole in that case, just considered as a generic case without think of grouping by individual universitites ...

Comment: no I didn't mean not using `GROUP BY` within the query @StoreCode , of course that should exist as having aggregations, but just to bring the last record independent from any of the universities.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: I retook my query and at the end i put 
GROUP BY
UNI_TEACH_NAME,
UNI_STAT
ORDER BY CAL_UPDATE
but doesn't work: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: you should add the column(`cal_update`) within the `ORDER BY` clause's list  to the `GROUP BY` list too @StoreCode . Indeed, don't forget to alias `MAX(CAL_UPDATE)` with `cal_update`

Comment: According to the initial query it doesnt require any grouping at all if you need just a single record per all the filtered group of rows. So the `group by` may be removed with the `max` in the select list

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i did, but i get still 2 more rows.
astentx can you put please as answer?

Comment: indeed, the column `call_status`(within the select list) should be removed or aggregated too @StoreCode

Comment: If `cal_status` will be aggregated (not with Oracle's `keep`, but simple aggregation) then the question became irrelevant, because: 1) you will not have duplicates anymore; 2) you will not preserve the relationship between `cal_update` and `cal_status`

Comment: yes, right @astentx from that point of view, thanks. eg, should directly be removed. Btw, it's interesting that there's one more column(`uni_stat`) in GROUP BY, while not in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a subquery and rank, you could use `KEEP...LAST` :

```
SELECT U.UNI_ID,
  U.UNI_TEACH_NAME,
  MAX(C.CAL_UPDATE) AS CAL_UPDATE,
  MAX(C.CAL_STATUS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY C.CAL_UPDATE) AS CAL_STATUS
FROM UNIVERSITIES U
LEFT JOIN CALENDAR C
ON U.UNI_ID = C.CAL_ID
AND C.CAL_NAME = 'REGISTRED'
WHERE U.UNI_MASTER = 'SO88'
AND U.UNI_STAT= 'OK'
GROUP BY U.UNI_ID,
  U.UNI_TEACH_NAME,
  TRUNC(C.CAL_UPDATE)
```

I've moved the `CAL_NAME` check into the outer join's `ON` clause; if it's in the `WHERE` clause then it will effectively turn it back into an inner join. So this will get one row per university per day that the calendar was updated: "I want just to get the max date for that date". And it will show nulls for the calendar fields if there is no matching calendar, since it's an outer join.

If you actually only want the latest update on *any* day then just remove the `TRUNC(C.CAL_UPDATE)` from the grouping:

```
SELECT U.UNI_ID,
  U.UNI_TEACH_NAME,
  MAX(C.CAL_UPDATE) AS CAL_UPDATE,
  MAX(C.CAL_STATUS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY C.CAL_UPDATE) AS CAL_STATUS
FROM UNIVERSITIES U
LEFT JOIN CALENDAR C
ON U.UNI_ID = C.CAL_ID
AND C.CAL_NAME = 'REGISTRED'
WHERE U.UNI_MASTER = 'SO88'
AND U.UNI_STAT= 'OK'
GROUP BY U.UNI_ID,
  U.UNI_TEACH_NAME
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72683484187b2c2eeaf301d515956919) with some made-up data; and also (just for fun) showing Gordon's query with the calendar name clause in both places to show the difference, and to show this gets the same result for that dummy data. (And [an 18c version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6c4b4aaac8d7a65a3bce88cd8d1d33c) which shows Barbaros' too; getting back a single row.)

Comment: the query looks good, but I get less rows (44). The weird thing is... why by left join it doesn't populate no match with null?

Comment: @StoreCode - it does; you can see that in the db<>fiddle. Without your original data, or at least a representative version of your data that demonstrates what you think is wrong, I'm not sure sure what to suggest.

Comment: thank you I will talk with my superior about that. Thanks